# Breaking a loop and returning to a menu

Tags: java, loops

Good evening everyone,

I am currently taking an intro to java class and I seem to be having a bit of an issue. Essentially the project is to create a system in which to intake rescue animals, reserve the animals, and print lists of the animals. The issue that I am having is that when I intake a new animal the program loops through all the questions and even adds the animal to the array, but just continues to loop through the questions. For example:
What is the dog's name: Fido
What breed is your dog: Lab
How old is your dog: 3
What is the dog's name: Fido
That dog is already in our system. Please try again.
What is the dog's name: Rex
What breed is your dog: Lab

and so on and so on forever. I'm uncertain where I am making my mistake. I've included my code below. Thanks for the help.

```
/**************************************************************
/*Program designed to input rescue animal information, reserve
/*rescue animals, and print lists of rescue animals.
/*Written by: Nicholas Phelps
/*Date: July 30, 2021
/**************************************************************/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
    private static ArrayList<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();
    private static ArrayList<Monkey> monkeyList = new ArrayList<Monkey>();
    // Instance variables (if needed)
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput;
        


        initializeDogList();
        initializeMonkeyList();
        
/***********************************************************************************
 * Do while menu loop that takes user input, validates, and executes menu option
 * Updated the menu validation to .equals("userSelection") instead of "=="
 **********************************************************************************/
        
        displayMenu();
        userInput = scanner.nextLine();
        
        do {
            if(userInput.equals("1")) {
                intakeNewDog(scanner);
            }
            else if(userInput.equals("2")) {
                intakeNewMonkey(scanner);
            }
            else if(userInput.equals("3")) {
                reserveAnimal(scanner);
            }
            else if(userInput.equals("4")) {
                printAnimals(scanner);
            }
            else if(userInput.equals("5")) {
                printAnimals(scanner);
            }
            else if(userInput.equals("6")) {
                printAnimals(scanner);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please enter a valid option.");
            }
            }while(!userInput.equals("q"));
    }
          

    // This method prints the menu options
    public static void displayMenu() {
        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tRescue Animal System Menu");
        System.out.println("[1] Intake a new dog");
        System.out.println("[2] Intake a new monkey");
        System.out.println("[3] Reserve an animal");
        System.out.println("[4] Print a list of all dogs");
        System.out.println("[5] Print a list of all monkeys");
        System.out.println("[6] Print a list of all animals that are not reserved");
        System.out.println("[q] Quit application");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a menu selection");
    }


    // Adds dogs to a list for testing
    public static void initializeDogList() {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Spot", "German Shepherd", "male", "1", "25.6", "05-12-2019", "United States", "intake", false, "United States");
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Rex", "Great Dane", "male", "3", "35.2", "02-03-2020", "United States", "Phase I", false, "United States");
        Dog dog3 = new Dog("Bella", "Chihuahua", "female", "4", "25.6", "12-12-2019", "Canada", "in service", true, "Canada");

        dogList.add(dog1);
        dogList.add(dog2);
        dogList.add(dog3);
    }


    // Adds monkeys to a list for testing
    //Optional for testing
    public static void initializeMonkeyList() {
        Monkey monkey1 = new Monkey("Marcel", "Capuchin", 9, 18, 18, "male", "2", "14.7", "11-13-2019", "United States", "intake", false, "United States");
        Monkey monkey2 = new Monkey("Ross", "Marmoset", 10, 19, 19, "male", "3", "15", "01-22-2018", "France", "in service", true, "France");
        Monkey monkey3 = new Monkey("Remy", "Squirrel Monkey", 6, 12, 12, "female", "2", "8", "04-01-2019", "United States", "Phase I", false, "United States");
        
        monkeyList.add(monkey1);
        monkeyList.add(monkey2);
        monkeyList.add(monkey3);

    }


/*******************************************************************************************************
 * Completed the intakeNewDog method that takes user input, validates that input and sets dog class 
 * variables. Then adds the new dog to the dogList array.
 ******************************************************************************************************/
    
    public static void intakeNewDog(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("What is the dog's name?");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        for(Dog dog: dogList) {
            if(dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                System.out.println("\n\nThis dog is already in our system\n\n");
                return; //returns to menu
            }
            else {
                dog.setName(name);
                System.out.println("What is the dog's breed?");
                String breed = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setBreed(breed);
                
                System.out.println("What is the dog's gender?");
                String gender = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setGender(gender);
                
                System.out.println("What is the dog's age?");
                String age = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setAge(age);
                
                System.out.println("What is the dog's weight?");
                String weight = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setWeight(weight);
                
                System.out.println("What is the dog's acquisition date?");
                String acquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setAcquisitionDate(acquisitionDate);
                
                System.out.println("What is the dog's acquisition country?");
                String acquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setAcquisitionLocation(acquisitionCountry);
                
                System.out.println("What is the dog's training status?");
                String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setTrainingStatus(trainingStatus);
                
                System.out.println("Is the dog reserved?");
                boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean(); scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setReserved(reserved);
                
                System.out.println("What is the dog's service country?");
                String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setInServiceCountry(inServiceCountry);
                
                Dog dog4 = new Dog(name, breed, gender, age, weight, acquisitionDate,
                        acquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry);
                
                dogList.add(dog4);
            }
            return;
            /**
             * Loop never ends and continuously adds dogs. Need a way to break loop
             */
        }
        
    }


/***************************************************************************************
 * Implemented intakeNewMonkey method that takes user input, validates that input, and
 * sets monkey variables. Then adds the new monkey to monkeyList
 **************************************************************************************/
    
        public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scanner) {
            System.out.println("What is the monkey's name?");
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            for(Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
                if(monkey.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                    System.out.println("\n\nThis monkey is already in our system\n\n");
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    monkey.setName(name);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's species?");                //Monkey Species
                    String species = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setSpecies(species);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's tail length?");            //Monkey tail length
                    int tailLength = scanner.nextInt();
                    monkey.setTailLength(tailLength);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's height?");                 //Monkey height
                    int height = scanner.nextInt();
                    monkey.setHeight(height);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's body lenght?");            //Monkey body length
                    int bodyLength = scanner.nextInt();
                    monkey.setBodyLength(bodyLength);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's gender?");                 //Monkey gender
                    String gender = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setGender(gender);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's age?");                    //Monkey age
                    String age = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setAge(age);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's weight?");                 //Monkey weight
                    String weight = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setWeight(weight);
                    
                    System.out.println("What was the monkey's aquisition date?");       //Monkey acquisition date
                    String aquisitionDate = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setAcquisitionDate(aquisitionDate);
                    
                    System.out.println("What was the monkey's aquisition country?");    //Monkey acquisition country
                    String aquisitionCountry = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setAcquisitionLocation(aquisitionCountry);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's training status?");        //Monkey training status
                    String trainingStatus = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setTrainingStatus(trainingStatus);
                    
                    System.out.println("Is the monkey reserved?");                      //Monkey reservation status
                    boolean reserved = scanner.nextBoolean(); scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setReserved(reserved);
                    
                    System.out.println("What is the monkey's service country?");        //Monkey service country
                    String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
                    monkey.setInServiceCountry(inServiceCountry);
                    
                    Monkey monkey4 = new Monkey (name, species, tailLength, height, bodyLength, gender, age, weight, aquisitionDate,
                            aquisitionCountry, trainingStatus, reserved, inServiceCountry);
                    
                    monkeyList.add(monkey4);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

/*******************************************************************************************
 * Implemented the reserveAnimal method that takes user input for type of rescue animal,
 * breed / species, and service country. Then validates that input to ensure that it is
 * valid user input and that there is a service animal of the chosen species/breed in 
 * the selected service country available. If there is then the animal is reserved and if
 * not then the system sends a message asking user to make a different selection.
 *******************************************************************************************/
        
        public static void reserveAnimal(Scanner scanner) {
            System.out.println("Enter type of rescue animal (dog or monkey): ");
            String rescueAnimal = scanner.nextLine();
            if(rescueAnimal.equals("monkey")) {
                System.out.println("Enter monkey species: ");
                String species = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter service country: ");
                String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
                for(Monkey monkey: monkeyList) {
                    if(monkey.getSpecies().equalsIgnoreCase(species) || monkey.getInServiceLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(inServiceCountry)) {
                        monkey.setReserved(true);
                        monkey.setInServiceCountry(inServiceCountry);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No rescue monkey of this species in selected service country.");
                        System.out.println("Please make another choice");
                        return;
                    }
                    }
                }
            else if(rescueAnimal.equalsIgnoreCase("dog")) {
                System.out.println("Enter dog's breed: ");
                String breed = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter dog's service country: ");
                String inServiceCountry = scanner.nextLine();
                for(Dog dog: dogList) {
                    if(dog.getBreed().equalsIgnoreCase(breed) || dog.getInServiceLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(inServiceCountry)) {
                        dog.setReserved(true);
                        dog.setInServiceCountry(inServiceCountry);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("No rescue dog of that breed in selected service country.");
                        System.out.println("Please make another choice.");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice. Please make a valid choice.");
                return;
            }

         }

        // Complete printAnimals
        // Include the animal name, status, acquisition country and if the animal is reserved.
    // Remember that this method connects to three different menu items.
        // The printAnimals() method has three different outputs
        // based on the listType parameter
        // dog - prints the list of dogs
        // monkey - prints the list of monkeys
        // available - prints a combined list of all animals that are
        // fully trained ("in service") but not reserved 
    // Remember that you only have to fully implement ONE of these lists. 
    // The other lists can have a print statement saying "This option needs to be implemented".
    // To score "exemplary" you must correctly implement the "available" list.
        public static void printAnimals(Scanner scanner) {
            String userInput;
            
            System.out.println("[1] Print all dogs");
            System.out.println("[2] Print all monkeys");
            System.out.println("[3] Print all available animals");
            System.out.println("[q] Exit");
            
            userInput = scanner.nextLine();
            
            while(!userInput.equals("q")) {
                
                if(userInput.equals("1")) {
                    for(Dog dog : dogList) {
                        System.out.println("Name: " + dog.getName() + ", Training Status: " + dog.getTrainingStatus() +
                        ", Acquisition Country: " + dog.getAcquisitionLocation() + ", Reserved Status: " + dog.getReserved());
                    }
                    return;
                }
                
                else if(userInput.equals("2")) {
                    for(Monkey monkey : monkeyList) {
                        System.out.println("Name: " + monkey.getName() + ", Training Status: " + monkey.getTrainingStatus() +
                                ", Acuisition Country: " + monkey.getAcquisitionLocation() + ", Reserved Status: " + monkey.getReserved());
                    }
                    return;
                }
                
                else if(userInput.equals("3")) {
                    System.out.println("This option needs to be implemented.");
                    return;
                }
                
                else {
                    System.out.println("Please meake a valid selection.");
                    break;
                }
            }
                
        }
}
```

Comment: the scanner.nextLine() should be moved into the do-while loop before the first if statement. This is because you want to always take an user input before an iteration occurs

Comment: You don't need to loop over the animals at all in your intake methods, just read an animal and add it to the list.

Comment: @tgdavies is correct.  Why are you using a for loop in intakeNewDog()?  The loop is entirely unnecessary.  That is the answer.  Remove the loop altogether.  If you want to check if the dogs name exists in the list write a helper method doesNameExist(String name) and you can loop through the list in that method.  You dont need to loop the questions

Comment: This absolutely solved my issue and really appreciate the tips. I also moved the printMenu() method into the loop after realizing that when the loop ended for intakeNewDog() it didn't actually show the menu again.

Answer (score 0):

You enter a line outside the loop and don't change it in the loop. So the loop never ends.

You need to move

```
userInput = scanner.nextLine();
```

to the loop

Second error in the method `intakeNewDog` when checking if the dog is already in the list. This method does not finish because you endlessly add dogs to the list and iterate over it endlessly. Carry out the dog existence check in a separate cycle

```
for(Dog dog: dogList) {    
    if(dog.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {               
        System.out.println("\n\nThis dog is already in our system\n\n");
        return; //returns to menu
    }
}
// add dog
```

Same for other animals.

Comment: That's a problem with the menu loop, but the animal intake problem is different.